# Error saving polygon with hibernate spatial and postgis

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, hibernate-spatial

I'm trying to persist a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon` in my PostgreSQL (with PostGIS enabled) database, using Hibernate and Hibernate-Spatial plugin.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: One can not infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.postgis.PGgeometry

It fired the below exception. What am I doing wrong?

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate.spatial}</version> //version 4.3
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>${version.vividsolutions.jts}</version> //version 1.13
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jdbc.postgis.version}</version> //version 2.1.3
        </dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="Test-PU">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/testDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
             value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <!-- Debug -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />

...
```

My module in Wildfly

modules/org/postgresql/main

```
module.xml
postgis-jdbc-2.1.3.jar
postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar
```

standalone.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS" pool-name="testDS" enabled="true"
 use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB</connection-url>
  <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
    <security>
       <user-name>postgres</user-name>
       <password>postgres</password>
    </security>
 </datasource>

<driver name="postgresql-driver" module="org.postgresql">
  <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Mapping

```
@Column(name = "perimeter", columnDefinition = "Geometry")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Polygon perimeter;
```

Comment: Hi @tmvolpato, there is a little example of how to use geometries on web apps on this link: https://github.com/carlosjrcabello/vraptor-geo/tree/master/controle-propriedade/src/com/wp/carlos4web/cpropriedades

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing hibernate spatial in your pom.xml

Here is the pom I used with PostGIS and Hibernate spatial

https://github.com/thesteve0/parkshibernatespatial/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Hi, @TheSteve0... I made the change and the problem continued.I'm thinking that the problem can be setup in wildfly server.